# What funny automatic-response do you know?

Tags: command, response

(I don't know how this kind of fun questions are dealt with in here, but I hope it doesn't get deleted (since it's not a dupe, it IS a question, it is (fairly) programming related)  just because it's not professional or really important)

[image: syntax error]
<sub>(source: [globalnerdy.com](http://globalnerdy.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/if_youre_happy_and_you_know_it.jpg))</sub>

I've come across [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJhZQ.jpg) and I went to windows prompt and noticed that it didn't work anymore:( instead it dealt with the code, and the "if" command had an interesting reaction on strange code, then I created [my own](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3045472/funAnswer.png) tricky 'question':

type in exactly:
"if jack, mike and john were invited, why were you surprised that mike showed up ?"

What are other funny interactions with automatic responses? (as in compilers, database managers and programming-related softwares?)

Edit: It's now community wiki as requested.

Comment: I don't know what's the drill about doing "fun questions", i just wouldn't want this to be deleted, since i've seen other non-closed fun questions around =)

Comment: Then make it CW at least. Questions with "best", "fun" are really typical candidates as they are often highly subjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic one is the error messages from the old Apple MPW C compiler:

> "String literal too long (I let you
>   have 512 characters, that's 3 more
>   than ANSI said I should)"
>
> "...And the lord said, `lo, there
>   shall only be case or default labels
>   inside a switch statement'"
>
> "a typedef name was a complete
>   surprise to me at this point in your
>   program"
>
> "`Volatile' and`Register' are not
>   miscible"
>
> "This struct already has a perfectly
>   good definition"
>
> "Only one parameter per register
>   please "
>
> "type in (cast) must be scalar; ANSI
>   3.3.4; page 39, lines 10-11 (I know you don't care, I'm just trying to
>   annoy you)"
>
> "This array has no size, and that's
>   bad"
>
> "Huh ?"
>
> "can't go mucking with a `void *'"
>
> "we already did this function"
>
> "The target of this goto is a label in
>   a block that has an automatic variable
>   with an initializer"
>
> "This label is the target of a goto
>   from outside of the block containing
>   this label AND this block has an
>   automatic variable with an initializer
>   AND your window wasn't wide enough to
>   read this whole error message"
>
> "Call me paranoid but finding `/*'
>   inside this comment makes me
>   suspicious"
>
> "This function has an explicit return
>   type and deserves a return value"
>
> "You are comparing two structures that
>   have holes in them"
>
> "Too many errors on one line (make
>   fewer)"
>
> "Symbol table full - fatal heap error;
>   please go buy a RAM upgrade from your
>   local Apple dealer"
>
> "Trailing comma not permitted in enum
>   definition. (This time I'm letting you
>   off with a warning)"